# How do I create a function that takes a string and returns dashes on the left and right side of every vowel (a e i o u)

Tags: javascript, string

Examples
dashed("Carpe Diem") ➞ "C-a-rp-e- D-i--e-m"
dashed("Fight for your right to party!") ➞ "F-i-ght f-o-r y-o--u-r r-i-ght t-o- p-a-rty!"
Notes

Comment: You'll want an array of vowel characters. Split the string, then map over each character checking to see if its in the array - if so, return a new character wrapped with dashes. Once mapped, rejoin the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const my_replacer = (str)=> str.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g,'-$&-')
let a = 'Carpe Diem'
console.log(my_replacer(a))
let b = 'Fight for your right to party!'
console.log(my_replacer(b))
```

Comment: Instead of `/[aeiouAEIOU]/g`, you can use `/[aeiou]/gi` or `/[AEIOU]/gi` where `i` makes the regex pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks @ArvindKumarAvinash for the additional info

Answer (score 2):

There are already a couple of solutions using regex; therefore, I am adding an answer which can be useful to someone who is not familiar with regex.

The following function, referenced by `formatVowels`, iterates the parameter string and uses [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check if any of the characters is a vowel; if yes, it prepends and appends `-` to it and then adds the resulting text to the variable, `result`, otherwise, adds the character as it is to the variable, `result`.

```js
const formatVowels = (str) => {
  if (str == undefined) return "";
  let result = "";
  for (const ch of str) {
    result += "AEIOU".indexOf(ch.toUpperCase()) != -1 ? "-" + ch + "-" : ch;
  }
  return result;
};

// Test
console.log(formatVowels('Hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
coolString = `Cookke`;

function dashed(coolString) {
  const regex = /a|e|i|o|u/gi;
  console.log(coolString.replace(regex, `-$&-`));
}

dashed(coolString);
```

Comment: Instead of `a|e|i|o|u`, you can use `[aeiou]`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.